# What to do with separate short url domain? Redirect to primary domain? .htaccess?

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, cross-domain, short-url

I'm using a drupal module that has an api to create short url's. It is configurable to use any domain for the short url's. When testing, I used my site's primary domain in creating short url's, and the links that are created work perfectly.

However, when I attempt using a separate short domain, the links are not being routed properly to the primary domain. I really hoped it would be as easy as just setting up a redirect from the short.url --> primarydomain.com, but that gives a 404 when a short.url is clicked.

If I don't use a redirect (in effect, doing nothing to short.url), I get a 500 error when clicking short.url/8d3j

It's clear to me that the code (drupal module) works perfectly, it's just that the maintainer does not believe in documenting code and there is absolutely no clue as to how to configure the separate domain. Anyone been in a similar situation? Does someone know of a couple lines of code to add to .htaccess that will magically solve my problems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're just looking for something to send all the requests to your short domain to your long domain, you might try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^longdomain\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://longdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

That's saying: if the host doesn't match my long domain, please ask the client to redirect to the requested path on my long domain.

Comment: Quick note that this needs to go fairly early in the stock Drupal .htaccess.

Comment: That's a good point - you don't want anything else to supersede your redirection, and you'd like to do as little as possible in this request, because it's just getting punted off to another request to the long domain.

Comment: Ironically your solution worked while the module developer's didn't.